# Why was は removed from this sentence?

Tags: grammar

So here is the sentence:

```
このスプーンすてきですね
```

Why didn't we say:

```
このスプーンはすてきですね
```

Isn't スプーン the topic of the sentence? Why did we remove it? Why did we leave it in a sentence like:

```
とうきょうはきれいです
```

Comment: You don't need to have "help" in the question title. This site is all about answering good questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Particles, especially は and を, are often omitted in colloquial Japanese. Formal Japanese would require the は to mark the topic, as you suggested. Compare

> ご飯食べる?

Comment: If you are suggesting, which you clearly are, that を is being omitted after 何か, I disagree.  「何かを食べない？」 sounds very unnatural to begin with.  With 何か it sounds much more natural without the を.  With a specific food name, however, it would have made a good example sentence.

Comment: @TokyoNagoya Thank you for your comment. I had ご飯食べる? first, but then changed it, because I wasn't sure how best to translate it into English.

Comment: @TokyoNagoya You can undo downvotes on a question/answer once they have been edited.